# How to create docker container for python beam pipeline and apache flink?

Tags: docker, apache-flink, apache-beam

I am a bit struggling to wrap my head around containerizing a beam pipeline written in python and executed by flink. Following official documentation, I thought that modifying an existing container image to make it compatible with Apache Beam Runners would be a good option.

I created this dockerfile, but now i struggle with how to add flink and how to make it all work together. Would it work by simply adding another layer with `beam_flink1.14_job_server` or `flink:1.14.6` image into dockerfile?

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

WORKDIR /pipeline

# Set the entrypoint to Apache Beam SDK worker launcher.
COPY --from=apache/beam_python3.7_sdk:2.38.0 /opt/apache/beam /opt/apache/beam
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/apache/beam/boot"]

# Install Java
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjdk-11-jre

# Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python3.7 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Set JAVA HOME
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
ENV PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"

# Copy Beam Pipeline
COPY config.json ./
COPY run_pipeline.py ./
CMD ["python3.7", "run_pipeline.py"]
```

Also my python pipeline by default starts `apache/beam_java11_sdk:2.43.0` on background ( I assume due to ReadFromKafka/WriteToKafka, which are not python native). Will be this handled by installing java in dockerfile?

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can modify an existing container image to make it compatible with Apache Beam Runners. You can add another layer with beam_flink1.14_job_server or flink:1.14.6 image into dockerfile. You can also install java in dockerfile to handle the default start of apache/beam_java11_sdk:2.43.0 on background (due to ReadFromKafka/WriteToKafka, which are not python native). This [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/) might help you.

Comment: Finally, i made my own container starting from an ubuntu image and installing all components (python, java, docker, flink ...). beam_flink_job_server didn't work for me. An important lesson learned here was that the cross-language functions as ReadFromKafka start by default the expansion docker service on the `host` network, so the main image needs to start on that one too (to see each other) and enable running docker from docker with `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`